# wallpaper changes depending on the time

Tags: javascript, time, background

I wanted to solve the problem of using javascript to change the background image of the  tag over time. if it's morning, it changes to a sunrise image, if it's evening, to an evening image.
I tried to write such a code using the Internet, but it didn't work.

My code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <section id="bg" class="banner"></section>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var now = new Date(); 
    var hour = now.getHours(); 
    var mintues = now.getMinutes();

    if(
        (hour*60 + mintues) > 570 && 
        hour <= 9
    )
    {
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('../pics/background1.jpg')";
    } else {
        if(
        (hour*60 + mintues) > 570 && 
        hour <= 18
    ) {
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('../pics/background2.jpg')";
        } else {
            if ((hour*60 + mintues) > 570 && hour <= 20) {
                document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('../pics/background3.jpg')";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('../pics/background4.jpg')";
            }
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working here? You don't see the background image at all?

Comment: No. I give the access path but it doesn't do anything, the background is white.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out the code provided and it is working fine as far as showing the background image is concerned. The only thing you might be missing is that the background image is working on the `<section>` tag, and there is nothing inside it, so it will not show anything unless you put some content or tag inside it. For example:

```js
<section id="bg" class="banner">Test</section>
```

Another thing you should note is that the placement of images should be correct. `..` simply goes to the parent folder, in the following example, it will refer to `mywebsite`, Your project should be in the following example folder structure:

- mywebsite (folder: with any other name)

  - app (folder: with any other name)

    - index.html
  - pics (folder)

    - background1.jpg
    - background2.jpg
    - background3.jpg

Also, you can simplify the logic as follows (here using `backgroundColor` instead):

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="bg" class="banner">test</section>
    </body>
</html>
<style>
    .banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<script>
    var now = new Date(); 
    var hour = now.getHours(); 
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    
    // Let's define 
    // morning as [6:00 - 12:00] == [6:00 AM - 12:00 PM]
    // afternoon as [12:00 - 17:00] == [12:00 PM - 5:00 PM]
    // evening as [17:00 - 20:00] == [5:00 PM - 8:00 PM]
    // night as [20:00 - 6:00] == [8:00 PM - 6:00 AM]
    if (6 <= hour && hour < 12)
    {
        // morning
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if (12 <= hour && hour < 17)
    {
        // afternoon
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (17 <= hour && hour < 20)
    {
        // evening
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
    else
    {
        // night
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried only with colors, but it doesn't work, it doesn't change the color

Comment: @Zsombor I have added the code, it should work